# Can't call a function inside the class instance

Tags: swift

I have a class `DiscoverUserInfo`, which has a function `compoundKeyValue`. I need to call this function in line 23 (see pic below). But I am getting the following error:

> Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> DiscoverUserInfo' has no member
>   'compoundKeyValue'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a method on `self` during initialization of `self`. Maybe you want to create a computed property instead?

```
public var compoundKey: String {
    return self.compoundKeyValue
}
```

That will also allow you to remove the `didSet` handler from `UserObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You may make the method `compoundKeyValue` static, as

```
static func compoundKeyValue() -> String {
    return UserObject.UserId
}
```

and create `compoundKey` as

```
public var compoundKey: String = DiscoverUserInfo.compoundKeyValue()
```